# Trouble with PHP inside HTMl inside PHP extended version

Tags: php, html, echo

I am developing some code for my School Website and I have a long php file. I need to echo html and in that I need to include php like so.

```
  echo '<p>. $url . </p>';
```

This seems to be working small amounts of Html Code but does not work with a lot of html code.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please define "a lot" and "does not work". What exactly is the limit you have found, and what exactly happens when you exceed it?

Comment: Single quotes will not process variables inside, and this is not how you concatenate strings.

Comment: A lot as in 317 lines of code. Should I post it? By Does not work I mean it shows blank.

Comment: @aynber Can you please demonstrate?

Comment: A little bit of basics helps you a long way: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: Something to consider if you start to want to separate the PHP and HTML (sort of) would to be look at some template engines -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197466/whats-a-good-templating-system-for-php

Comment: Can you show the opening PHP tag? In your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62644708/trouble-with-php-inside-html-inside-php-extended-version#comment-110782813) below, it appears that you're using `short_tags` which is discouraged but also disabled on some setups. I think it may even be removed in PHP 7+. This could account for why you're not seeing anything on screen. It's possible the PHP isn't even processing...

Answer (score 0):

Try like that !

```
 echo '<p>'.$url.'</p>';
```

you must enclose text before and after a variable 'text'.$var.'text'; and thats goes for concatenate variables on variables to

Comment: echo '<p><?  echo '<p>'.$message.'</p>';
?> </p>';
Shows a parse error

Comment: Well this will work on any part of the code if it is well applied

Comment: <p><?php echo $message; ?> </p>

Comment: that's unnecessary my friend since your question is not over open or close php code which i see was you problem right now it is nothing wrong on it just must be more careful about it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the single quotes php variables treats as a text not like variables, so if you want to use your php variable with html tags you can either enclosed it with double quotes like below

```
  echo "<p> $url </p>";
```

Or you can concatenate php variable with strings or html tags

```
//with single quotes
echo '<p>'. $url . '</p>';
//With double quotes
echo "<p>". $url . "</p>";
```

May this will help you.
Happy Coding!