# Is it possible to echo text stored in DB that has PHP echo statements in it

Tags: php, html, mysql, echo

So a bit of a strange question, within my mysql database I have a column which holds text. Within that text field HTML code, plain text and several PHP echo statments.

When I echo out the contents of that column, the text and HTML comes out fine and is layed out correctly but the echo statements are just text.

For example, in a DB column is stored this:

```
Some text some text <b>some html</b> some text some text
<img src="../Images/Blog/<?php echo($blogimage);?>" class="imagetext-wrap" alt="<?php echo($blogtitle);?>">
```

Now that echo's out as

```
Some text some text **some html** some text some text
    <?php echo($blogimage);?> <?php echo($blogtitle);?>
```

The variables $blogimage and $blogtitle already hold the values from the other columns of the DB, is there a way for them to display from the text column field when it is echo'd out?

This is quite hard to describe so I hope you get what I am asking

Comment: Well you could [eval()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) it but, depending on how that data gets into the database to begin with, it could be a big security risk (as per the warning in the documentation). How did you end up with this situation in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a good templating system for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197466/whats-a-good-templating-system-for-php)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, a friend of mine has a website where they have been using php variables to store sections of their blog on each page the blog pages exist. So there are three pages that have the same text on three different pages. So if they update their blog they have to update all 3 pages. So I said I would put it all in a DB and then they just need to call it on each page. But as the main text on the blog page has images everywhere and part of the image links is a PHP variable. I just hoped I could copy that all into the DB and echo it out the text and the variables would echo

Comment: But I think I am just going to have to manually change the links. It will be fine going forward but all their old posts will need to be changed. Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

its like this if you question

echo "<img src="../Images/Blog/'.$blogimage.' " class="imagetext-wrap" ">

Comment: you seem to have completely missed the point of the question